How to dismiss all toasts from BlueprintJS with shift click dismiss?
I have an Alert component which is basically built with BlueprintJS Toast component:
import { OverlayToaster, Intent, ToasterPosition } from "@blueprintjs/core";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "redux/hooks";
import actions from "redux/alert/actions";

function Alert() {
  const alert = useAppSelector((state) => state.alert.alert);
  const alertTimeout = useAppSelector((state) => state.settings.alertTimeout);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState<ToasterPosition>("top-right");

  // reference to blueprint toaster
  const toaster = useRef<OverlayToaster>(null);
  const getTimeout = useCallback(
    (type: Intent) =>
      type === "success" ? alertTimeout.success : alertTimeout.error,
    [alertTimeout.success, alertTimeout.error]
  );

  // set alert to undefined after display
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const removeAlert = useCallback(
    (isManuallyDimissed: boolean | undefined) => {
      dispatch(actions.SET_STATE({ alert: undefined }));
      if (isManuallyDimissed) {
        toaster.current?.clear();
      }
    },
    [dispatch, toaster]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (alert) {
      setPosition(alert.position);
      toaster.current?.show({
        message: alert.message,
        intent: alert.type,
        timeout: alert.isManualDismiss ? 3000000 : getTimeout(alert.type),
        onDismiss: () => removeAlert(alert.isManualDismiss),
      });
    }
  }, [dispatch, alert, getTimeout, removeAlert]);

  return <OverlayToaster position={position} ref={toaster} />;
}

export default Alert;

I actually want to be able to dismiss all toast messages when I shift + dismiss one of the toasts. I havent found a way how to, so I decided to dismiss all the toasts onDismiss when it is manually dismissed. However, when I try to execute toaster.current?.clear(), I get a maximum call stack size exceeded.
